# SQL SELECT 2 table with include 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I want create a select in MSSQL (SSMS).
 I have 2 tables :

Solds:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Solds](
    [Short] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Id_Sold] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [float] NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
```

Fruits:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fruits](
    [Short] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL,
```

And now I want to select  ALL name of fruits and Price , include Fruits without price.

I wrote this :

```
SELECT Name.Fruits,Solds.Price FROM Solds
join 
Fruits on Fruits.Short = Solds.Short
```

And this code show me only all Sold fruits,
The question is how can I add here the names of fruit that have not been sold?

I want output for example:

```
Carrot   1,20
Cucumber 2,80
Carrot   9,20
Orange   NULL  --  NULL or Blank
```

Just want to union Fruits  that have not been sold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT f.Name,
       COALESCE(s.Price, -1.0) AS Price
       -- include the following if you want a label for sold/unsold
       -- CASE WHEN s.Price IS NOT NULL THEN 'Sold' ELSE 'Not Sold' END AS status
FROM Fruits f
LEFT JOIN Solds s
    ON f.Short = s.Short
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro ! You're awesome

Answer (score -1):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN:`

```
SELECT f.Name,
isnull(s.Price, 0) AS Price
FROM Fruits f
LEFT OUTER JOIN Solds s
    ON f.Short = s.Short
```

You can get more details about various joins from below mentioned link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx